# What does "DNS Error code: 0x00002741" mean?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows

Is there a list somewhere? When I search for "DNS Error code: 0x00002741", all I ever find are netdiag logs. So does anyone know the meaning or can provide me with a list of error codes?

Comment: It's an error that occurs when running netdiag when a host fails to re-register it's hostname with the DNS server (but you probably caught that much already). Can you give us more information, for example, when are you getting this error (if not with netdiag)?

Comment: it is with netdiag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x00002741 means the SVR record requested is invalid. Without a context to put that in, it just mean that a program is looking for a SVR record and not finding what it expected.

The most common reason to get this, as you have found, is when someone runs netdiag and the AD DC's DNS entries aren't registered correctly, a missing SVR record, or the A record it points to is missing, or one of them is corrupted, or something else entirely (such as the DNS server couldn't be contacted).

[Reference to MS's unbelievably cryptic documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199%28PROT.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Wow. "The requested address is not valid in its context." could mean anything. But thanks!